# Play Framework 2 - How to create a custom log file in scala

Tags: file, scala, playframework

I am working with play framework and scala and I'd like to create several log files instead of using the default log file for everything.

I suppose I have to specify the route of the file(.log) I want to write in but I don't know how neither where. And I think I have to create a .scala file to define my logger but I don't know what to put inside.

Anyone knows how to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Configuration of the logging is explained in the documentation here : [Settings Logger](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger)